# How can I copy a file content to another file, but change some lines of it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can get the file content and split it, but how can I change like the  line 5 to something else?

How can you «call» the lines? The result would look something like this:

```
const fs = require("fs)
fs.readFile('./some/path/file.js', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    content = data;     

});
var something = \n
var result = content.split(something)
//now ho can i get all the lines before 5 and all the lines after 6?
var 5 = //lines before 6
var 6 = //lines after six
//so i could just do
var final = 5 + \n + result + 6 + \n + result //???
//so it would be a one variable again
console.log("one variable " + final)
```

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. Right now it seems like you are missing some important pieces of your code for us to help understand your problem, and your question seems unclear.

Comment: The safest would be to use a placeholder in the original file if you want to insert stuff at a defined place. Or you can still count the number of new lines. However, you should come back when you tried something and have a specific problem to ask..

Comment: If you have it all in one string, you could split it by lines a la `some_string.split("\n")`, but what have you tried so far, and what part are you getting stuck at?

Comment: Now its hopefully easier to understand